# How to install Gazebo for Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble

Tags: gazebo-11, docker

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs

Yields:

gazebo

gazebo: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-fuel_tools4.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZN8ignition4msgs12FuelMetadataC1EPN6google8protobuf5ArenaE

sudo apt install gazebo

Yields:

gazebo

gazebo: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-fuel_tools4.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZN8ignition4msgs12FuelMetadataC1EPN6google8protobuf5ArenaE

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28361/how-to-install-gazebo-for-ubuntu-22.04-with-ros2-humble/) by [EdSeymore17](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/97435/edseymore17/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 26 on 2022-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

On a clean Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS2 Humble Hawksbill image:
sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs
results in a suscessful start for:
gazebo cmd.

---

Originally posted by [EdSeymore17](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/97435/edseymore17/) with karma: 26 on 2022-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hapy-capy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/115951/hapy-capy/) on 2022-12-22**:
Was this on amd64 or arm64? I'm looking to install on a Raspberry Pi (arm64) and `ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs` is not located, nor is `ros-humble-desktop-full`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!

Maybe you can try to install first lib ignition

```
sudo apt -y install libignition-common-dev
```

Also, try

```
sudo apt install -f ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs
```

I have everything working on Ubuntu 22 with ROS 2 Humble

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [cristinaluna](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/103331/cristinaluna/) with karma: 11 on 2022-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Desktop-full installs all of the needed ROS packages and Gazebo
`sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop-full`

---

Originally posted by [MarqRazz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46737/marqrazz/) with karma: 21 on 2022-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1